# Connecting another MacBook and using their RAM/Memory?

Tags: macbook-pro, memory

As a person with a rather bad MacBook Pro speed (only have 4GB, and it is currently using 3.5GB with about 1.5GB being compressed memory) at the moment, I'm wondering if it is possible to connect another MacBook pro, MacBook or any other computer and use their RAM/Memory alongside the memory I already have on this computer.

Is this possible? If it is, how would I go about doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible, because the overhead of keeping the two sets of hardware in sync would far outweigh the benefits provided therein.

How old is your MacBook? If it is old enough the RAM may be removable / upgradable.

Answer (score 0):

Put simply, no. Computer hardware doesn't work like that; you have to either install some more memory ([iFixIt's guides](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Early+2011+RAM+Replacement/5117) are quite useful, for instance) or switch computers.

Of course, if you have some scientific/heavy simulation workload you can always [setup a computing cluster](http://bonsai.hgc.jp/~mdehoon/software/cluster/software.htm), but I'm assuming this is not the kind of work you have in mind for your MacBook.